# Is there any way to open url only for Appstore reviewer?

Tags: ios, private, vpn, environment, openurl

We are developing a website.
This url is "http://dev.abcd.com/", for example.
When we finished it, the url must be chage to "http://www.abcd.com/"

This website is eligible for web and app. (using responsive UI)
So we also are making iOS app based on WKWebView.
Not just for bundle a website, but also including native based experience.

Now we are developing using private network or virtual private network.
Before launching this service, iOS app must be review, so we have to open our private url to appstore reviewer.
But we want to launch the service after iOS review complete, so user can access web and app at the same time.

How can we provide open url for just apple iOS reviewer before service launch?

And in this case, how do you usually deal with this case?
Could we give them VPN information?

Comment: Could you simply create a redirect on the server side for the time being? Otherwise another API call would need to be done before anything else happens in the app which checks which base URL to use overall.

Comment: @MaticOblak Thanks for reply. The problem is not about switching url but if we open url for review, anyone who get this url can access before we launch the site. We want to release web and app at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If possible I would always try to avoid doing this. Note that Apple would probably reject your review for doing this but if they don't know...

What we used in some application was a sort of a configuration file. We had a local (default) version of it but otherwise a file downloaded from our server which would define things like which URLs to use. The largest problem that this produces is that you need to open arbitrary loads and allow your app to access any URL at any time. This makes a nice opportunity for a possible attacker to make the app do pretty much anything simply by hacking the configuration file. Otherwise it is a pretty simple procedure: When app launches request server for a configuration file. If it succeeds save it to local library and continue. If it fails check local library for latest version of config and use that one. If no file is present in local library (never got a config from server) then use the one in resources (default).

Another approach I would prefer is to manager redirects on the server side. This way you can persist your URLs as they are but on server side enable redirect to your development server. I am not sure how many issues this may present on backend though.

Another way is doing things time based. If you plan to put your app in review much before you will release it into app store you could use URLs depending on the current time (date). Imagine you put your app in review in beginning of September but will release it in beginning of October. The problem with this is that you can not rely on device time. You would need to use some endpoint just to get current time. I guess this would still be safer than getting any URL from backend but from any other perspective this is pretty much the same as the first solution.

Whichever case you use there is also a potential issue that URL changes during runtime. Or that the app was in background for a long time and the URL changes. Usually there are systems running like having some models that are paging or a list having an item that leads to details with old URL... In short you will most likely still have a bunch of old URLs which all need to be replaced. The easiest solution for this is to "accidentally" crash the app. Otherwise there are relatively easy solutions like recreating the whole view controller hierarchy but is still a bit of work.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I also prefer to redirect url on serverside. I thinks this is the most safe way to switching environment by app condition or time or something. But the problem is “www.asdf.com” is already serviced site not supporting responsive UI. We need to “update”(not first launch) web and app at the same time. So we can’t use old url(www.asdf.com) for redirection.

Comment: @AutumnSky How about using a third URL; Imagine having "http://prod.abcd.com/" which would now redirect to "http://dev.abcd.com/" and when you get ready start redirecting to "http://www.abcd.com/". It seems wasteful though.

Comment: Yes, that could be one solution for switching url. But the point is, any url you open for review (could be “prod.abcd.com”). someone can figure out this url, can access even the site was not released. Suppose that the release date is Oct. 1st. for website and app at the same time. But if you know this “prod.abcd.com” url can access earlyer. I hope I can make you understand.

Comment: @AutumnSky Actually you lost me here. How could anyone guess that? All they see is “prod” which would redirect to "dev". In no location is there any information of what your end URL will be. So how could anyone access anything but "dev"?

Comment: I thought there are many ways to guess the development url. In my example, dev url is easily guessed out just changing "www" to "dev". And also may be google search engine can save dev url for cache.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do exactly what you want unless your app allows the user to set the url themselves once they start the app.

This is because when you submit the app for review you have to submit the build that will get released in the app store. You cannot change the code that will be released after it has been reviewed. So even if you get the app with the test url reviewed in order to release the app with the updated url you will have to get it reviewed again.

One work around could be to have the production url "http://www.abcd.com/" redirect to the dev one "http://dev.abcd.com/" for now. After the app is reviewed you can remove the redirect and release the app. 
You could also implement an api call that the app can make once it starts that would return the appropriate base url. That way you can change the base url any time you want.

One thing to keep in mind is that when you release the app in the App Store connect it will not go live everywhere at once. It could be 10 minutes or it could be 24 hours. So you would need to make the production url available once you release the app but the app itself might not appear in the store for another day.

Comment: Thank yo for reply. As you said, We made api call that send us url. So app can decide which url to connect. My question is, this url could be “dev.asdf.com” or “www.asdf.com” or whatever. The problem is, if we open this url for reviewer, the site can be accessed anyone who know this url. We want to release website and app at the same time.

Comment: Well any url that you make public can potentially be used. However if only the Apple reviewer can see it then I doubt someone else can use it. Also if you use a completely random url like "randomcheapurl.com" then the chances of someone guessing that would negligible.

Comment: I doubted this is the only way to prevent access from users before we launching except allow apple reviewer. And wondered what solution other company have.